# android ActivityManager cannot be resolved as a type

Tags: android

I'm trying to determine the size of an LruCache depending on the device's memory, so I was trying to do something like:

```
int memClass =
  ((ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();
```

but the compiler is giving an "ActivityManager cannot be resolved as a type".

Does anyone know why this is happening? At first I thought that the API I was using was too old, but ActivityManager says its been around his API 1. haha.

This is the tutorial I was reading: 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Thanks!

Comment: If you're in Eclipse, do CTRL + SHIFT + O to fix imports. Or outright `import android.app.ActivityManager;`

Comment: wow thanks! I thought that wasn't the problem because usually it explicitly says to import the class. x__x haha. =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always make sure to have all the classes you need imported. If you're in Eclipse, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to clean up imports (auto-import everything that is needed, deletes what isn't needed). You can also outright

```
import android.app.ActivityManager;
```